# Java Database Poller?

Tags: java

Are there any JAVA API's for polling a database.

Should be able to

**a)** Be able to get all the data from a table to start with.
  **b)** Poll it every configurable minutes.

Comment: Please make it a little clearer :]

Answer (score 2):

In principle JDBC combined with the Timer class should be enough to handle the requirement that you have set forth.

The [Timer API page](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) describes how to schedule a task, that can be fired periodically.  The [wikipedia page on Java Database Connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) contains a pretty good code sample on how to query all the data on a specific table.   Tying these two items together should give you what you want.

There is more complicated ways to achieve what you desire, such as using Quartz as a Job Scheduler.  But for such a simple application, I would probably stick with the build-in libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, that's what an entity bean does.

So, if you feel like it, run your code in a EJB container :) I'm half-serious : you could configure it to be very lightweight (Tomcat+OpenEJB for example), and ejb 3 won't make your code dependant on that technology. That would avoid writing any code for this task.

Sun doc:

> An important parameter for tuning
>   read-only beans is the refresh period,
>   represented by the deployment
>   descriptor entity
>   refresh-period-in-seconds. For CMP
>   beans, the first access to a bean
>   loads the bean’s state. The first
>   access after the refresh period
>   reloads the data from the database.
>   All subsequent uses of the bean uses
>   the newly refreshed data (until
>   another refresh period elapses). For
>   BMP beans, an ejbLoad() method within
>   an existing transaction uses the
>   cached data unless the refresh period
>   has expired (in which case, the
>   container calls ejbLoad() again).
>
> This parameter enables the EJB
>   component to periodically refresh its
>   “snapshot” of the database values it
>   represents. If the refresh period is
>   less than or equal to 0, the bean is
>   never refreshed from the database (the
>   default behavior if no refresh period
>   is given).